# how do i extract the part between the brackets in javascript regular expressions: answer_postal_address[address]

Tags: javascript, regex

how do i extract the part between the brackets in javascript regular expressions:

answer_postal_address[address]

I tried this:

```
/^\w*/g
```

which works but i wasn't sure if this was correct...

Comment: My colleague said this: (\w*)\[(\w*)\]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matches `input` of value of any *word character* followed by anything inside of bracket, i.e. answer_postal_address[address]

```
  var re = new RegExp("\w+\[([^\]]+)\]");
  var m = re.exec(input);
  if (m == null) {
    alert("No match");
  }
  else {
    alert("Matched: " + m[1]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this be sufficient?

Search for: `\([.*?]\)`

Replace with: `$1`

So

```
result = str.replace(/\((.*?)\)/g, "$1");
```

Comment: Oops, I misread your sample, apparently you used square-brackets. I have corrected (edited) the regex a bit.